# Error de conexión en Terminal de iPython de Spyder (Anaconda): "Conectándose a Núcleo"

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Tengo instalado Spyder(3.3.6) de Anaconda con Python 3.7.3 (64 bits), en Windows 10. Al abrir el editor Spyder, el terminal de iPython se queda colgado sin abrir el núcleo y con el mensaje

> Conectándose al núcleo

He intentado muchas cosas que he leído en otras preguntas pero ninguna me ha funcionado:

- Desactivar el antivirus antes de cargar el Spyder y el terminal iPython
- Eliminado Anaconda y lo he vuelto a instalar
- Actualizado iPython...

Y nada. Sigue apareciendo el mensaje cuando abro el Spyder. El Terminal de iPyhton no conecta y se queda en el mensaje anterior.

Comment: En [esta pregunta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802860/ipython-console-in-spyder-stuck-on-connecting-to-kernel) hay muchas respuestas, cada una proponiendo una solución diferente. Pruébalas a ver si alguna....

Comment: Otra solución que he visto por ahí es actualizar a la última versión `ipkernel`, mediante el comando `pip install ipykernel --upgrade` ejecutado desde alguna terminal en la que `pip` esté accesible.

Comment: Al final lo solucioné desinstalando Anaconda, iPython y Spyder de Windows. Pero al hacerlo, aún hay carpetas que quedan ahí. Las borré. Me volví a descargar e instalar Anaconda, y ya funcionó. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné desinstalando Anaconda, iPython y Spyder de Windows. Pero al hacerlo, aún hay carpetas que quedan ahí. Las borré. 
Las carpetas que eliminé fueron:

- .anaconda .cache, .conda, .config, .ipython, .matplotlib, .spyder-py3

Me volví a descargar e instalar Anaconda, y ya funcionó. Gracias

Comment: Por supuesto. Las carpetas que eliminé fueron: .anaconda, .cache, .conda, .config, .ipython, .matplotlib, .spyder-py3

Comment: Gracias. ¿Sabes que puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta?